# how to add buttons in the centre with long text on windows phone project page throug stackpanel

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I am facing a freaking problem in windows phone project.I am designing a page with two buttons on the centre of the page,here is the xaml code:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="Mainpg00" Visibility="Visible">
            <Button Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200" Click="Button1_Click" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Button.Content>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Generate Registration OTP"/>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>

        <Button Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="200" Click="Button2_Click" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Button.Content>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Proceed with OTP"/>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
        </StackPanel>
```

The problem I am facing is that I am unable to set the buttons on the centre of the page.
plz help.

Answer (score 0):

If with centered you mean this:

[image]

Then, set the Orientation property of the StackPanel to Horizontal. Here you have the code:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <StackPanel x:Name="Mainpg00" Visibility="Visible" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200" Click="Button1_Click" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Button.Content>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Generate Registration OTP"/>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>

        <Button Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="200" Click="Button2_Click" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Button.Content>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Proceed with OTP"/>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Otherwise, if what you want is this:

[image]

Then play with alignments and Button sizes:

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <StackPanel x:Name="Mainpg00" Visibility="Visible" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Click="Button1_Click" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Button.Content>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Generate Registration OTP"/>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>

        <Button Click="Button2_Click" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Button.Content>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Proceed with OTP"/>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```